# Consuming IAsyncEnumerable<string> with server side rendered Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Using this code I was able to consume and update the DOM in the browser live.

```
<button type="button" @onclick="PopulateText">Click</button>
<p>@((MarkupString)_generatedText)</p>
@code {
    private string _generatedText = string.Empty;
    private async Task PopulateText()
    {
        await foreach (var text in Start())
        {
            _generatedText += text;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    private async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            yield return i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to consume a `IAsyncEnumerable<string>` from a service I have injected the DOM is only updated after the `IAsyncEnumerable<string>` is finished generating.
The service does a HTTP request to OpenAI and streams the text back using a `IAsyncEnumerable<string>`. [The call to OpenAI can be found
here.](https://github.com/betalgo/openai/blob/ebfb7af6f6d1db6c2ab335eda7054e026542f194/OpenAI.SDK/Managers/OpenAIChatCompletions.cs#L20)

```
<button type="button" @onclick="PopulateText">Click</button>
<p>@((MarkupString)_generatedText)</p>
@code {
    private string _generatedText = string.Empty;
    private async Task PopulateText()
    {
        await foreach (var text in _openAiService.GenerateText(new GenerateTextRequest("hei")))
        {
            _generatedText += text;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

When adding breakpoints, I can see that `_generatedText` is being populated and `StateHasChanged()` is called. Nevertheless, the DOM does not update.

I was hoping that a backend call could easily be streamed back to the client side through some server side rendered magic, but this is obviously not the case.

My thoughts on this is that I am missing a crucial bit of knowledge on how the server side rendered blazor application is working.

Why are these two ways of consuming `IAsyncEnumerable<string>` handled differently?

*Update 1:*

After feedback, I have tried adding a `yield return` in the service method.

old code:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<string> GenerateText(GenerateTextRequest request)
{
    return _generateService.GenerateTextAsync(request);
}
```

updated code:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GenerateText(GenerateTextRequest request)
{
    await foreach (string text in _generateService.GenerateTextAsync(request))
    {
        yield return text;
    }
}
```

This did not help, but adding it as documentation of things tried.

*Update 2:*

Tried overriding the `ShouldRender()` to force render the DOM. Unfortunetly, this did not work either.

```
    private string _generatedText = string.Empty;
    private bool _shouldForceRender = false;
    private async Task PopulateText()
    {
        await foreach (var text in _openAiService.GenerateText(new GenerateTextRequest("hei")))
        {
            _generatedText += text;
            _shouldForceRender = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        if (_shouldForceRender)
        {
            _shouldForceRender = false;
            return true;
        }

        return base.ShouldRender();
    }
}
```

*Update 3:*

To reproduce the request to the external service you can use this code:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<string> GenerateText(GenerateTextRequest _)
{
    return TestServiceCall();
}

private async IAsyncEnumerable<string> TestServiceCall()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    using var response = httpClient.PostAsStreamAsync("https://httpbin.org/post", new { text = "test text" });
    await using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    // Continuously read the stream until the end of it
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        // Skip empty lines
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            continue;
        }

        string text = null!;
        try
        {
            text += line;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            line += await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            text += line;
        }


        if (null != text)
        {

            yield return text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is my test code which works as expected.

There's a very important fact that you may not know:

`StateHasChanged()` doesn't render the component.  It places a `RenderFragment` on the Renderer's queue.  When that queue gets serviced (by the Render) depends on what code is running on the UI (Dispatcher) thread.  If the code is synchronous (with no yields) then the actual render doesn't happen until a yield occurs at the completion of the synchronous code block.

What you are seeing suggests:

```
await foreach (var text in _openAiService.GenerateText(new GenerateTextRequest("hei")))
```

is probably synchronous code masquerading as asynchronous.

Here's my Test Service:

```cs
    public class MyService
    {
        public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetCountriesAsync()
        {
            foreach(var country in _countries )
            {
                await Task.Delay(500);
                yield return country;
            }
        }

        private List<string> _countries = new() { "France", "UK", "Spain", "Portugal" };
    }
```

And my `Index`:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject MyService Service
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>


<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @onclick="GetCountriesAsync">Get Countries Async</button>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>
        @_messages.ToString()
    </pre>
</div>

@code {
    private StringBuilder _messages = new();

    private async Task GetCountriesAsync()
    {
        await foreach (var country in Service.GetCountriesAsync())
        {
            _messages.AppendLine(country);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I changed the service method so that it does a yield (See update 1)

Comment: I tried the sample you gave, but unfortunetly it did not work. I have also added a link to the method i am using to call openAI. I am still curious about the `StateHasChanged()` not triggering. Some variations on exactly that call is that i have tried to override `ShouldRender()` to return true, if it is writing to dom. I can add the code in a update 2.

Comment: I have added a sample request to an external service under update 3